# RESTkit unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to add a person class via iPhone to my server.

I have the following code and I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Person object]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x5fe6c' error

```
@interface Data : NSObject {
Person *person;
NSArray *dogs;
}
@property (nonatomic ,retain) Person *person;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) NSArray *dogs;
@end

@interface Person : NSObject {

NSString *name;
NSNumber *personId;
NSDate   *updatedAt;
NSDate   *createdAt;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDate * createdAt;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSDate * updatedAt;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSNumber  *personId;
@property (nonatomic , retain) NSString *name;
@end

RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Person class]];

[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"personId"];

RKObjectMapping* dogMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Dog class]];
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"person_id" toAttribute:@"spersonId"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"]; 
[dogMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"dogId"]; 

RKObjectMapping *dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Data class]]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"dog" toAttribute:@"dogs"]; 
[dataMapping mapKeyPath:@"person" toRelationship:@"person" withMapping:userMapping]; 
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:dataMapping]; 

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/people"       
objectMapping:dataMapping delegate:self]; 


-(void)createObject{

RKObjectRouter * router = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router;
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people/:personId"];
[router routeClass: [Person class] toResourcePath:@"/people"          
forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
Data *data =[[Data alloc]init];
Person *daveLiu = [Person object];
daveLiu.name = @"Dave Liu";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:daveLiu delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: what does this line mean? Person *daveLiu = [Person object]; Shoudn't that be alloc] init]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

OK, you have an invalid argument exception. Why?

> reason: '+[Person object]:

A class method called `object` was called on the Person class

> unrecognized selector sent to class 0x5fe6c' error

... but the Person class doesn't implement the `object` class method. Looking at your implementation of Person, we can see that this is the case.

So, where are we calling this from? A quick scan through <strike>mja's comments</strike> the code shows us this line:

```
Person *daveLiu = [Person object];
```

Which is probably your culprit. As mja says, this should probably be

```
Person *daveLiu = [Person alloc] init];
```

Comment: [object] is a method of NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord, and is supposed to insert an entity into context without boilerplate code. It fails because restkit is imported incorrectly.